# How to get access_token from google oath2 into a class library

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

In a net class library, I have to call this google service.

https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/PUBLICATION_ID/entitlements?access_token=GSI_ACCESS_TOKEN

We already register in google console our website, so the users can access it with their google credentials too.

But now we need a service to retrieve the subscription data, stored in google, for any of the users already registered.

I know the value for `PUBLICATION_ID` but don't know how to get `GSI_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

In NuGet, there are many libraries to access google API, which one to use to retrieve access tokens?

Can anyone point me some sample code?

Thanks.

Comment: Where you asked to provide callback url during application setup in google?

Comment: in the google console my company created a new oath client type -> web application with no callback url. that console provides an option to create a new service account, i think i need this type of account to call that api from a class library.

Comment: Normally when you get a response from a call you would get json/xml response which should contain the token at which point you would deserialize it and get what you need.  Are you able to check the response using debugger and ensure you get the token back?

Comment: to call this https://subscribewithgoogle.googleapis.com/v1/publications/PUBLICATION_ID/entitlements?access_token=GSI_ACCESS_TOKEN you need to set the access_token. my problem is that i don't know how to retrive that access_token

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) and see if it helps